# How the replacer function works in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have read about the replacer function and am unable to understand how it operates. I [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter)
it here. The article explains the replacer but what it doesn't explain is from where the final output gets its keys from? If you see the function, we are only returning the value. The output should only contain the "values" but it contains keys too. If we aren't returning the keys then how the keys are in the output? I understand that for the first call the replacer function receives an empty key and the complete object as its value, therefore it prints in the first call:

`key
let meetup = {
title: "Conference",
occupiedBy: [{name: "John"}, {name: "Alice"}],
place: room
};`

And in the second call, the key "title" is used as the replacer's key parameter, and the value "Conference" is used as its value parameter. The if statement checks whether the key is not empty and if the value equals "meetup" and if the statement is true it returns "undefined", otherwise it returns only value. Here I am getting confused. Why we are only returning the value? If we are only returning the "conference" value then how is the key "title" getting returned if we didn't return it?

```js
let room = {
  number: 23
};

let meetup = {
  title: "Conference",
  occupiedBy: [{name: "John"}, {name: "Alice"}],
  place: room
};

// circular references
room.occupiedBy = meetup;
meetup.self = meetup;

console.log( JSON.stringify(meetup, function replacer(key,value){
  console.log('keys', key);
  console.log('value', value);
  if ( key != "" && value == meetup){
    return undefined;
  }
  else {
    return value;
  }
},3));
```

Comment: The key just stays as-is. If you want to use different keys, the previous call needs to return a different object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacer function's only purpose is to (possibly) change the value returned. The key used at that position in the stringified object is known and constant in `JSON.stringify`'s internals. Just because it also takes a parameter of the key does not mean that what is returned is *used* as the key.

For a trivial example of transforming an object with a function that takes a key and a value, but only changes the value, see here:

```js
const transformObj = (obj, replacer) => {
  const newObj = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    const transformedValue = replacer(key, value);
    newObj[key] = transformedValue;
  }
  return newObj;
};

console.log(transformObj(
  { foo: '5', bar: '10' },
  (key, value) => Number(value)
));
```

The key can be passed to the replacer without requiring the replacer to also return a new key somehow.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify() seems to be treat replacer() like that:

```
    function stringify(json, replacer,spaces){
        tempJson=replacer("",json)

        //stringifyFunctionBody
        (tempJson,spaces?.length??spaces ) =>{}

        // return stringified json
        return tempJson;
    }
```

According to comment:
JSON.stringify takes replacer() firstly to operate on Your JSON input, then he really operates on what Your replacer returned.
*JSON.stringify(json,replacer)* is identical to:

```
let json={...};
    let replacedJson = replacer({...json})
    JSON.stringify(replacedJson)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer